# HoloLens - Unity: Cursor does not align to Cube

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, augmented-reality, hololens

So right now I have a this hierarchy: Cube → Canvas → RawImage

What I want to do is, clicking on the rawimage that represents a screenshot of a webpage. Then getting the coordinates of the click back and send it to my server.

How I get the coordinates:

```
public class ClickAction : MonoBehaviour, IInputClickHandler{

public IBrowserClient Client;

public void OnInputClicked(InputClickedEventData eventData)
{
    Vector3 hitPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(GazeManager.Instance.HitPosition);
    Vector2 clickedPos = new Vector2(hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y);

    Client.SetClick((int)Math.Ceiling(clickedPos.x), (int)Math.Ceiling(clickedPos.y));
}
```

**My problem:**
My canvas accepts raycast, it has Graphic Raycaster:
[image]
And the RawImage accepts raycast too:
[image]

So the problem is when Im running it on the hololens the cursor appears not aligned to the cube, its like 1cm above. Like if there is a invisible wall in front of the cube.

[image]

**What I noticed**: If I deactivate Graphic Raycaste on the canvas, my cursor works fine and alignes to the cube, but I cant trigger my OnInputClicked-Event. **How can I triggere my events and get the cursor aligned to the cube?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collider for this technique instead.